# How to convert a point from a small area to a big area in the same scale with Java?

Tags: python, java

I want to convert a point from a rectangle area  to a mapping rectangle area which convert point is in the same scale.

For instance, the samll area has 4 points from (mx0, my0) to (mx3, my3), and the big area is from (x0, y0) to (x3, y3) .

Now that can get the input (intput_x, intput_y) to get the output (x,y) as the follow:
input (100, 100), get output (0, 0).
input (150, 100), get output (1920, 0).
input (100, 150), get output (0, 1080).
input (150, 150), get output (19200, 1080).

Assume the intput (intput_x, intput_y) = (110, 120), and the output (x, y) can get (384, 432).

The described as the diagram: [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sSDK.jpg).

Here is the python code:

```
import numpy as np

def interp(x, xp, fp, is_loop_test=True):
    if (is_loop_test==True):
        for i in range(100, 151):
            bb = np.interp(i, xp, fp)
            print(f'{i}, bb: {bb}')
            return bb
    else:
        return np.interp(x, xp, fp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    in_x, in_y = 110, 120

    xp = (100, 150)
    fp = (0, 1920)

    yp = (100, 150)
    fyp = (0, 1080)

    x, y = interp(in_x, xp, fp, False), interp(in_y, yp, fyp, False)

    print(f'(x, y): ({x}, {y})')
```

I can using numpy interp() function to get the output with Python. However, I want to implement the same thing with Java without using numpy.

I have found the similar liner interp function named evaluate() in Java, I calculated the input x: 110, and the output was 251.40625.

It's not my expect value 384. I have no idea where is wrong.

Here's the Jave code:

```
public class Interp{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        
        float fraction = 0.078125f;  // 150/1920=0.078125f
        float startValue = 110.0f;   // intput x
        float endValue = 1920.0f;    // 0 to 1920     
        
        float aa = evaluate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        System.out.println("x: " + aa);
     
    }
    
    public static Float evaluate(float fraction, Number startValue, Number endValue) {
        float startFloat = startValue.floatValue();
            return startFloat + fraction * (endValue.floatValue() - startFloat);
        }

}
```

Could you help me or give me some idea to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would help if you explained what part of the conversion you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use library like [apache commons math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) to do same thing as numpy.

It is not recommended to implement it by yourself, it is difficult to do better.

Class `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.LinearInterpolator` meets your needs.

Code Example:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.LinearInterpolator;
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.polynomials.PolynomialSplineFunction;

// Test on commons-math3 version 3.6.1
public class InterpolatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // will output 384.0
        System.out.println(interpolator(110f, new double[]{100d, 150d}, new double[]{0d, 1920d}));
        // will output 432.0
        System.out.println(interpolator(120f, new double[]{100d, 150d}, new double[]{0d, 1080d}));
    }

    public static double interpolator(double value, double[] x, double[] y) {
        LinearInterpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
        PolynomialSplineFunction function = interpolator.interpolate(x, y);
        return function.value(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. It's help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help. I think I can solve it!

Here is my solution :D

Python version:

```
def interp(input_vlaue, small_area, big_area):

    small_area_x = small_area[2][0] - small_area[0][0]
    big_area_x = big_area[2][0] - big_area[0][0]
    
    small_area_y = small_area[2][1] - small_area[0][1]
    big_area_y = big_area[2][1] - big_area[0][1]

    out_x = (big_area_x / small_area_x) * (input_vlaue[0] - small_area[0][0])
    out_y = (big_area_y / small_area_y) * (input_vlaue[1] - small_area[0][1])

    output = [out_x, out_y]
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    intput_poiint = [110, 120]

    small_area = [(100, 100), (150, 100), (150, 150), (100, 150)]
    big_area = [(0, 0), (1920, 0), (1920, 1080), (0, 1080)]

    convert_output = interp(input_vlaue=intput_poiint, small_area=small_area, big_area=big_area)

    print(f'\nintput_poiint: {intput_poiint}')
    print(f'\nconvert_output: {convert_output}')
```

Java version:

```
public class Interp{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        float [] intput_value = new float[2];
        float [] small_area_left_up_point = new float[2];
        float [] small_area_right_down_point = new float[2];
        float [] big_area_left_up_point = new float[2];
        float [] big_area_right_down_point = new float[2];
        float [] fraction_small = new float[2];
        float [] fraction_big = new float[2];
        float [] output = new float[2];
        
        intput_value[0] = (float) 110;
        intput_value[1] = (float) 120;
        
        small_area_left_up_point[0] = (float) 100;
        small_area_left_up_point[1] = (float) 100;
        
        small_area_right_down_point[0] = (float) 150;
        small_area_right_down_point[1] = (float) 150;
        
        big_area_left_up_point[0] = (float) 0;
        big_area_left_up_point[1] = (float) 0;
        
        big_area_right_down_point[0] = (float) 1920;
        big_area_right_down_point[1] = (float) 1080;
        
        fraction_small[0] = small_area_right_down_point[0] - small_area_left_up_point[0];
        fraction_small[1] = small_area_right_down_point[1] - small_area_left_up_point[1];
        
        fraction_big[0] = big_area_right_down_point[0] - big_area_left_up_point[0];
        fraction_big[1] = big_area_right_down_point[1] - big_area_left_up_point[1];
        
        output[0] = interp(intput_value[0], fraction_small[0], fraction_big[0], small_area_left_up_point[0]);
        output[1] = interp(intput_value[1], fraction_small[1], fraction_big[1], small_area_left_up_point[1]);
        
        System.out.println("(intput_x, intput_y): " + intput_value[0] +", "+ intput_value[1]);
        System.out.println("(output_x, output_y): " + output[0]  +", "+ output[1]);
    }
    
    public static Float interp(float input_value, float small_fraction, float big_fraction, float mapping_left_point){
        return (big_fraction/small_fraction) * (input_value-mapping_left_point);
        
    }
    
}
```

Both version input (110, 120) can get the output (384, 432).
I am pleased to convert it! :D